# Spring boot run with properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to pass properties for spring boot project from command line.
I have following configuration in my **yaml** config file:

```yaml
server:
    port: ${port}
```

but when I starts project from command line like:

```bash
java -jar myapp.jar -Dport=8085
```

I get following error:

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'port' in value "${port}"
```

Did I miss anything in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`java -Dserver.port=8085 -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: sorry this one java -Dserver.port=8085 -jar myapp.jar

Comment: Actually it works with following line = java -Dport=8085 -jar myapp.jar. Thanks for you help! But I have another question - why do I need to pass properties before jar definition but when I pass profile like -Dspring.profiles.active=... I can put it after myapp.jar definition?

Comment: let's see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port

Comment: According to [Java SE Documanetation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html),
 `-Dproperty=value` is one of an `Options` while launching a Java application and it should be put in front of **-jar**.

Comment: You can also write it like this: `java -jar myapp.jar --server.port=9090`